# Magmi No configurable attributes found for configurable sku:

Tags: magento, magmi

I've been looking at all of the information that people have posted about configurable products with Magmi and Magento.  I've made sure my simple product SKU's are children to the configurable product. But I still get the Error of No Configurable attributes found.  Here is the data

```
store   websites    attribute_set   type    category_ids    sku has_options name    image   small_image thumbnail   url_key url_path    page_layout options_container   country_of_manufacture  msrp_enabled    msrp_display_actual_price_type  gift_message_available  price   weight  status  is_recurring    visibility  tax_class_id    description short_description   news_from_date  qty min_qty use_config_min_qty  is_qty_decimal  backorders  use_config_backorders   min_sale_qty    use_config_min_sale_qty max_sale_qty    use_config_max_sale_qty is_in_stock low_stock_date  notify_stock_qty    use_config_notify_stock_qty manage_stock    use_config_manage_stock stock_status_changed_auto   use_config_qty_increments   qty_increments  use_config_enable_qty_inc   enable_qty_increments   is_decimal_divided  stock_status_changed_automatically  use_config_enable_qty_increments    product_name    store_id    product_type_id product_status_changed  product_changed_websites    meta_title  meta_description    meta_keyword    ring_size   custom_design   special_price   msrp    recurring_profile   custom_layout_update    news_to_date    special_from_date   special_to_date custom_design_from  custom_design_to
admin   base    ring-size   configurable    3   CZ-Ring-001 1   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test  /s/t/sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-68_1.gif   /s/t/sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-68_1.gif   /s/t/sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-68_1.gif   sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test    sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test.html       Block after Info Column     No      No  19.99       Enabled     Catalog, Search Taxable Goods   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Hand-crafted Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring. Intricately designed Sterling Silver creates a very unique and elegant look! Embellish your beautiful hand with this piece!       0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test  0   configurable            Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring                                         
admin   base    ring-size   simple      CZ-Ring-001-5   0   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-5                sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-5  sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-5.html             No      No  19.99   1   Enabled No  Catalog, Search Taxable Goods   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Hand-crafted Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring. Intricately designed Sterling Silver creates a very unique and elegant look! Embellish your beautiful hand with this piece!       4   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-5    0   simple          Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring 5                                       
admin   base    ring-size   simple      CZ-Ring-001-9   0   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-9                sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-9  sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-9.html             No      No  19.99   1   Enabled No  Catalog, Search Taxable Goods   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Hand-crafted Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring. Intricately designed Sterling Silver creates a very unique and elegant look! Embellish your beautiful hand with this piece!       5   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-9    0   simple          Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring 9                                       
admin   base    ring-size   simple      CZ-Ring-001-7   0   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-7                sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-7-1    sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-7.html             No      No  19.99   1   Enabled No  Catalog, Search Taxable Goods   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Hand-crafted Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring. Intricately designed Sterling Silver creates a very unique and elegant look! Embellish your beautiful hand with this piece!       5   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-7    0   simple          Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring 7                                       
admin   base    ring-size   simple      CZ-Ring-001-7.5 0   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-7.5              sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-7-5    sterling-silver-clear-heart-cz-ring-test-7-5.html       Block after Info Column     No      No  19.99   1   Enabled No  Catalog, Search Taxable Goods   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Hand-crafted Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring. Intricately designed Sterling Silver creates a very unique and elegant look! Embellish your beautiful hand with this piece!       5   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1           1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring - Test-7.5  0   simple          Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring Sterling Silver Clear Heart CZ Ring 7.5
```

Comment: My tip in all such cases is to manually create one set of products and export them from Magento. That should give you a good guide as to if you've got the right set of attributes, the right syntax, etc. You can then modify your magmi file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [Blinkdata](https://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-configurable-item-processor/):

> The simple products need to appear BEFORE the configurable products.
>   If you do it the other way around, the simple products may not exist
>   in Magento and cannot be added to the configurable product.

**Solution:** First make sure you have the *Configurable Item processor* plugin enabled. Secondly, when importing configurable & simple products in the same CSV file, make sure the simple products appear first. Otherwise import them in two separate files (and import the simple products file first).